# MySQL database engine: MyISAM for information_schema but InnoDB for other databases

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, information-schema

I am currently using InnoDB for all my databases in MySQL, however I just noticed that my information_schema database uses MyISAM for tables that are not MEMORY.

I am in the process of investigating an InnoDB/MyISAM issue. While I don't think this is the cause of it, I am worried about this mixing. The database was originally set up with MyISAM. Later the my.cnf file was updated to reset the engine to InnoDB. I am using MySQL 5.5.10.

**What are the possible issues that could occur with having your information_schema database set to MyISAM, but all your other databases set to MySQL?**

---

**For those looking for help:** 
If you came across this question in search of an answer or you want to know more, to see your default database engine:

```
show variables;
```

To see the engine assigned to tables in a database:

```
show table status;
```

My my.cnf settings:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
log=/usr/local/var/mysql/mysqld.log
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
lower_case_table_names=2
default_storage_engine=InnoDB

# Performance hacks:
innodb_flush_method=nosync
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
```

Answer (score 4):

The storage engine used is on a per-table basis. The default storage engine is used when creating a new table and you don't specify a storage engine for the new table.

The system tables would have been MyISAM regardless of what you set the default storage engine to.

From [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html):

> Important
>
> Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database (such as user
>   or host) to the InnoDB type. This is an unsupported operation. The
>   system tables must always be of the MyISAM type.

If you are not querying the information_schema tables directly, there is no concern about mixing the types.